# Problema que en JComboBox no aparece ningun item añadido por el coclo for que dentro de si contene añadir item que contiene la variable de for

Tags: java

Estaba aprendiendo de como meter al boton color con la biblioteca "java.awt.*", probando hacer que en un interfas se eliga lo tnalidad de tres colores, rojo, verde y azul.

Al final no me aparecen los numeros que programe en cada JComboBox (del 1 al 255).

Dejo el codigo debajo por si alguien pueda ayudarme:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Formulario extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private JLabel label1,label2,label3;
private JComboBox combo1,combo2,combo3; 
private JButton boton1;

public Formulario(){
 setLayout(null);
 
 label1 = new JLabel("Rojo");
 label1.setBounds(10,10,100,10);
 add(label1); 

 combo1 = new JComboBox();
 combo1.setBounds(120,10,50,30);
 for(int i = 0 ; i > 255 ; i++){
  String string = Integer.toString(i);
  combo1.addItem(string);
  }
 add(combo1);

 //se repite lo mismo con los demas dos pero canviando el nombre de las variables

 boton1 = new JButton("Fijar color");
 boton1.setBounds(10,130,100,30);
 add(boton1);
 boton1.addActionListener(this);
 } 

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

 if(e.getSource() == boton1){

  String cad1 = combo1.getSelectedItem().toString();
  String cad2 = combo2.getSelectedItem().toString();
  String cad3 = combo3.getSelectedItem().toString();

  int rojo = Integer.parseInt(cad1);
  int verde = Integer.parseInt(cad2);
  int azul = Integer.parseInt(cad3);

  Color color = new Color(rojo,verde,azul);
  boton1.setBackground(color);
  }
 }
public static void main (String args[]){

 Formulario formulario1 = new Formulario();
 formulario1.setBounds(0,0,190,220);
 formulario1.setVisible(true);
 formulario1.setResizable(false);
 formulario1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 }
}
```

Este es el cogigo y al ejutarlo por el terminal y por "Replit", no me muestra los numeros del JComboBox

Gracias por la futura (espero) ayuda d>

Comment: estas poniendo esto "i > 255" "i" debe ser menor no mayor "i < 255"

Comment: Pero al final del ciclo for yo el i implemento por 1 y quiero  que el ciclo ce para quando se ha ejecutado 255 veces.

Comment: si i =0;i>255;i++ esto no se cumplirá por que i es 0 nunca sera mayor que 255 debe ser menor i<255 e i debe tomar el valor de 1 osea int i=1;i<=255;i++

Comment: Tienes razon.Muchas gracias. Pon como respusta y pongo que es la mejor